# pgfplots - Changing power in Scientific Notation

Tags: pgfplots

For xtick labels, when I enter 0.002, it appears as 0.2 x 10^{-2} on the axis, while I want it to appear as 2 x 10^{-3}. Have tried changing the precision but that only changes the trailing zeros. How to control this?

Here is the code that I am running:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,baseline]

\begin{axis}[
     y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=1,
        /tikz/.cd
    },

    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=1,
        /tikz/.cd
    },
     xmin=0, xmax=0.01,
     ymin=0.5, ymax=1,
     yticklabel style = {font=\normalsize} ]

     \addplot[color=red, mark=o, thick, fill=none] coordinates{
  (0,1)
  (0.002,0.8)
  (0.004,0.75)
  (0.006,0.7)
  (0.008,0.65)
  (0.01,0.6)
     };

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always provide a small but compilable example document that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `/pgf/number format/sci`?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,baseline]

\begin{axis}[
     y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=1,
        /tikz/.cd
    },
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=1,
            sci,
        /tikz/.cd
    },scaled x ticks=false,
     xmin=0, xmax=0.01,
     ymin=0.5, ymax=1,
     yticklabel style = {font=\normalsize} ]

     \addplot[color=red, mark=o, thick, fill=none] coordinates{
  (0,1)
  (0.002,0.8)
  (0.004,0.75)
  (0.006,0.7)
  (0.008,0.65)
  (0.01,0.6)
     };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can always configure your own number format using `xticklabel`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,baseline]

\begin{axis}[
     y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=1,
        /tikz/.cd
    },
    xticklabel={$\pgfmathparse{1000*\tick}%
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=0}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult\cdot10^{-3}$%
    },scaled x ticks=false,
     xmin=0, xmax=0.01,
     ymin=0.5, ymax=1,
     yticklabel style = {font=\normalsize} ]

     \addplot[color=red, mark=o, thick, fill=none] coordinates{
  (0,1)
  (0.002,0.8)
  (0.004,0.75)
  (0.006,0.7)
  (0.008,0.65)
  (0.01,0.6)
     };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another possibility using `scaled x ticks=manual`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,baseline]

\begin{axis}[
     y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=1,
        /tikz/.cd
    },
    scaled x ticks=manual:{$\cdot10^3$}{\pgfmathparse{#1*1000}},
     xmin=0, xmax=0.01,
     ymin=0.5, ymax=1,
     yticklabel style = {font=\normalsize} ]

     \addplot[color=red, mark=o, thick, fill=none] coordinates{
  (0,1)
  (0.002,0.8)
  (0.004,0.75)
  (0.006,0.7)
  (0.008,0.65)
  (0.01,0.6)
     };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but similar, as I want the same multiplier for all the numbers.

Comment: @King008 So you want `10*10^{3}` instead of `1*10^{-2}`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @King008 Added, please see the update.

Comment: Thank you very much, that does it nicely. Btw, is it possible to show the multiplier i.e., 10^{-3} on the side of the scale, instead of with every tick?

Comment: @King008 Yes, this is even simpler: `scaled x ticks=manual:{$\cdot10^3$}{\pgfmathparse{#1*1000}},` .